Is there a reason that the McCallister house has a doggie door?
Is there a reason why the McCallister family has a doggie door since there's no mention that I'm aware of in the final film of the family owning a dog? Something in supplemental material or an earlier draft of the script?

I see there is an answer to this, but just wanted to add a comment. If the dog hadn't been mentioned, it could have been possible that they were not the original owners of the house. There was already a doggie door and they decided not to replace the entire door and thought that perhaps someday they would get a dog.

They have the door for a dog mentioned in the movie
According to this transcript and this transcript, they put the dog in boarding while they are going on their vacation in France.
Kate McCallister (Catherine O'Hara) mentions it on the telephone in the opening scene

[on the phone] No, we're not bringing the dog, we're putting it in the kennel for the...

You can hear it in this clip



[Even without this line, this isn't really a plot hole. One could assume they had boarded a dog with family/friends or a kennel as they were traveling the next morning, or simply the previous owners had installed the door]

Everything's getting a downvote this week

"One could assume they had boarded a dog with family/friends or a kennel as they were traveling the next morning, or simply the previous owners had installed the door" Or they could have a had a dog that died.

Yeah, I considered including that too.  I guess my main point is that its not a plot hole, there are any number of reasons why they would have such a door. Its interesting though that they considered it important enough to include it in the script for the phone call.

@iandotkelly, it seems like the writers went the extra mile in including these types of details. For example, the way that Kevin's boarding pass gets thrown out by mistake so that later it isn't noticed that he's missing when the boarding passes are being handed out.

"Kennel can mean a business which boards dogs for owners, not just a small 'house' for a dog." I think it's safe to say that in the US, the word kennel is almost always used to mean the former. Maybe regional but a 'small house for a dog' is called a 'doghouse' in the US. I've never heard anyone in the US call a 'doghouse' a 'kennel'.

@JimmyJames - when researching this, I've seen people confused by the use of Kennel this way, and in the UK Kennel can mean both.  I'm from the UK and live in the USA and sometimes I can be over-cautious about ensuring the right meaning is understood.  Perhaps I should give people the benefit of the doubt and remove that.

There is nothing wrong with clarifying. I was more just asserting that the meaning of the dialog isn't in doubt. The phone call confirms the dog was boarded and this is the correct answer.

@JimmyJames, Anecdote: Growing up in Rural northern California valley, Kennel more often mean a dog crate (a dog house that locks closed). Terms like "dog boarding" or "doggie daycare" were more common. Especially the verb "kenneling" meant to lock the dog up in a crate. When I used the term in this way in Metro Oregon to locals, they understood without confusion. :shrug:

@TopherIsSwell That's interesting. I would never have guessed. I've never heard that in the East. Just 'crate'.  Now we need someone from Chicago to weigh in. I think we can infer from the context that it meant boarding, regardless. I can't see the family locking their dog in a cage and then taking off for Europe.

They own a dog, Ralphy. It's mentioned in the official novelisation.

"Uncle Frank won't let me watch the movie," he shouted. "If the big
kids can, why can't I?"
"Shush," Kate said. Then to the phone she said, "We put Ralphy in the
kennel... what? No, Ralphy's the dog. I gave them the office number in
case there's a problem."
... [later]
"With the Pepsi it comes to fourteen dollars and eighty cents," the boy said.
Kevin carefully pulled the money out of his pocket and pushed it through Ralphy's doggie door. Then he fast forwarded and hit the "play" button again.
"Keep the change, you filthy animal," the gangster snarled.

